# JavaScript Replace space

Tags: javascript

Below a part of code for replacing the spaces in a filename. 
This should be pretty straight and simple. 
But it is not working and ignores the empty spaces.

The "name" is like : GG Amberg Süd VF 5611

Is should after like: GG_Amberg_Süd_VF_5611.csv

What is wrong / or can I do better\?

```
var name = feature.attributes["name"].replace(" ", "_");
var filename = feature.attributes["name"] + "_" + feature.attributes["id"] + ".csv";
```

I also tried it with, but also ignored the spaces

```
var name = feature.attributes["name"].replace(/\s/g, "_");
var filename = name + "_" + feature.attributes["id"] + ".csv";
```

Comment: I think you meant to use `name` in the second line of your code to generate the `filename` as `name` holds the result of `replace`.

Comment: ... `var filename = name + "_" + feature.attributes["id"] + ".csv";`

Comment: also, when you use a string as first arg of `.replace()`, it only replaces the first instance, not all instances. You will need use a regex object with global flag to global replace: `.replace(/ /g,'_')`

Comment: can't I first set it to name - and then - recall it it as filename? Or is the "name" not the same as just name without the " "? The feature.attributes["name"] call a function and searches a column named "name". thats wy I use it like this

Comment: Your regex works ...

Comment: @BjorntenBroeke `replace` doesn't mutate the original string. It just use it to generate a new string and returns it. `feature.attributes["name"]` after the call to  `replace` will remain the same as before the call. You should use the variable `name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stored result of replacement in var name, but seems you don't use this variable bellow.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.replace(/ /g,"_");`

```
var str = 'a b c';
var replaced = str.split(' ').join('_');
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use replace method and also split with join.

```js
//using splict & join method
console.log("*using split method All Char contact with underscore".split(' ').join('_'))


//using replae method
console.log("Using replace method Char contact with underscore".replace(/ /g,'_'))
```